# No property customize found for type with QuerydslBinderCustomizer in Kotlin

Tags: spring, kotlin, spring-data

I have a CRUD app, created with Spring REST data in Kotlin.

```kotlin
@Repository
interface OrderRepository : PagingAndSortingRepository<Order, Long>, QuerydslPredicateExecutor<Order>, QuerydslBinderCustomizer<QOrder> {

    override fun customize(bindings: QuerydslBindings, root: QOrder) {
        bindings.bind(root.address.name)
                .first(StringExpression::containsIgnoreCase)
    }
}
```

I have customized my QuerydslPredicateExecutor, as per some examples, when I run the above application, I get an initialization error from Spring which says:

```
org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property customize found for type Order!
```

Which I assume might be a Kotlin problem, potentially it's not compiling how Spring would expect and is now trying to create a new data access function instead of just customizing the QueryDSLBinder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**A possible solution**

Usage of Kotlin's experimental `@JvmDefault` annotation on the method will fix the issue.

```kotlin
@JvmDefault
override fun customize(bindings: QuerydslBindings, root: QOrder) {
    bindings.bind(root.address.name)
        .first(StringExpression::containsIgnoreCase)
}
```

*It should be noted that you need to add `-Xjvm-default=enable` to the compiler args*